# try catch doesn't work in firebase Auth flutter

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I try to create user with firebase auth but when i put an existing email the app is crashing and try catch doesn't work but its work in firebase store when i add some Fields
i search and trying a lot but nothing helped me

This is my code:

````
Future<void> signUp() async {
    try {
      final newPlayer = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: playerEmail, password: playerPassword);
      if (newPlayer != null) {
        playerUser = newPlayer.user;
      } 
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      if (e.code == 'weak-password') {
        print(e.code);
        Alert(
                context: context,
                title: 'كلمة السر ضعيفة ',
                style: AlertStyle(
                    titleStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Cairo',
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.black)))
            .show();
      } else if (e.code == 'email-already-in-use') {
        Alert(
                context: context,
                title: 'الإيميل مسجل مسبقاً',
                style: AlertStyle(
                    titleStyle: TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'Cairo',
                        fontSize: 20,
                        color: Colors.black)))
            .show();
      } 
    }}
  Future<void> addPlayerInfo() async {
    try {
       await players.add({
   'userId': playerUser.uid, 
  'name' :playerName,
  'email':playerEmail,
  'phone' : playerNumber,
  'gender': playerGender,
});
    } catch (e) {
      print (e);
      Alert(
          context: context,
          title: 'حصل خطأ ما',
          style: AlertStyle(
              titleStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Cairo', fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black))).show();
    }
  }```
````

Comment: Do you get any error message on the console when the app crashes?

Comment: Yes i got 'pjava.lang.ClassNotFindException' and check permission begin

Comment: Please include the full error in your question.